# Objective c supporting iphone6/6+ resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm trying to make my app support iphone6/6+ resolution.
Currently my app is just scaled and doesn't look nice.
I've found many solutions using storyboard, with using size classes.
However, I have lots of codes manipulating the frame,
for example

```
self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
```

something like this.

Is there easy way of supporting 6/6+ resolution when I have lots of such codes ? Or do I have to change it one by one by detecting screen size and calculate each one ?

Comment: Absoute screen coordinates are always a code smell. You should change that in either case.

Comment: Are you using a launch screen storyboard? If not, do you have the appropriate iPhone 6/6+ launch images?

Comment: I've added 6/6+ launch images to support them

Comment: If you have the proper launch images then your app will be shown in full device resolution instead of scaling.

Comment: Yes it worked. But some parts where I used such code gives me smaller ui in 6+

Comment: You can always use [[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size] to get the CGSize for the current device screen then create your frames using that info. This approach works, but you will have to cover cases when the screen changes size, such as rotation or when you receive a call. You could also create views and create autolayout constraints in code that scale properly for multiple screen sizes.